# How do i make an pdf that contains image(from img.src) with nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf

I'm making a scraper downloader Project
With Node Js Cheerio and axios

What I've done :
Loading the web
I've Get all of the image source links from the website

What I need:
make it as a pdf

I'm figuring what best to make a pdf with

and how to do it

If you guys can help me I would be very helped

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-pdf

```
var fs = require('fs');
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test/businesscard.html', 'utf8');
var options = { format: 'Letter' };
 
pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
  if (err) return console.log(err);
  console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }
});
```